# How to show the vector $V=C_1V_1+C_2V_2+C_3V_3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $V_1,V_2$, and $V_3$ are mutually perpendicular non-zero vectors in 3D and $V$ any vector in 3D. How could I show that $V=C_1V_1 + C_2V_2 + C_3V_3$ where $C_i = (V\cdot V_i)/\lvert V_i\rvert^2$

Answer (score 1):

$V\cdot V_i= C_i\mid V_i\mid ^2$ because $V_i\cdot V_j=0$ for $i \neq j$ because of perpendicularity.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on MLT's answer:

your three vectors live in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and being mutually perpendicular means (although is not the same as) they are linearly independent. Thus you are assured that *such* an expression must exist. To actually recover what the coefficients $C_i$ must be, you take the inner product of $V$ with $V_i$.

Comment: Can you expand little more on subject or suggest a reference to where the definition of V.Vi=Ci|Vi|^2 comes?

Comment: So how that proves that V=C_1V_1 + C_2V_2 + C_3V_3

Comment: I found a way to get the V

Comment: @user95616 if you accept that we can write $V = C_1 V_1 + C_2 V_2 + C_3 V_3$, then our assumption on perpendicularity means $V_1 \cdot V_2 = 0, V_1 \cdot V_3 = 0, V_2 \cdot V_3 = 0$. then use the linearity of the dot product and you can see that $V \cdot V_1 = C_1 V_1 \cdot V_1 + C_2 V_2 \cdot V_1 + C_3 V_3 \cdot V_1 = C_1 V_1 \cdot V_1$, and now rearrange for $C_1$. the other two are found with the same method